# Linking an extra object file

Tags: cuda, makefile, qmake

I am using qmake to manage the build of a CUDA project. I'd like to
use the separate compilation feature of CUDA 5.0, which means that
the device code must be linked together before being linked to the
rest of the code.

I've managed the intermediate linking step by adding this to my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_PRE_LINK = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc $$CUDA_GENCODE -dlink $(OBJECTS) -o dlink.o
```

This creates an extra object file called `dlink.o`, which should be added to the array of objects to be linked by g++, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Peeking into the Makefile, I notice that the linker is passed an additional variable called `OBJCOMP`, but it is not defined and I can't find a way to access it through qmake.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `.pro` file:

```
LIBS += dlink.o
```